# CodeDom.CompileAssemblyFromSource throws weird error

Tags: c#, mono, codedom

My app compiles a portion of javascript code from source file on the fly with CodeDom. On Windows, everything works fine. But running the app on Linux ends up throwing InvalidOperationException, which provides no useful information to debug. What is the root cause in this situation?

I tested the app on Debian Jessie with Mono 4.0.x

```
private JScriptCodeProvider compiler = new JScriptCodeProvider();
private CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
```

**Parameters:**

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
```

**Compile:**

```
// This line throws InvalidOperationException
var result = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, scriptCode);
```

**Trace info:**

```
e   
{System.InvalidOperationException: Process has not been started.  
at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_ExitCode () [0x00015] in <filename
unknown>:0    

at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
System.Diagnostics.Process:get_ExitCode ()   

at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.InternalExecWaitWithCapture
(System.String cmd, System.String currentDir,
System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection tempFiles, System.String&
outputName, System.String& errorName) [0x000f1] in <filename
unknown>:0    

at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture
(System.String cmd, System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection
tempFiles, System.String& outputName, System.String& errorName)
[0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0    

at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeCompiler.Compile
(System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[]
fileNames, Boolean keepFiles) [0x0009c] in <filename unknown>:0    

at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeCompiler.FromSourceBatch
(System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[]
sources) [0x0006b] in <filename unknown>:0    

at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeCompiler.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch
(System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[]
sources) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    

at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource
(System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[]
sources) [0x00014] in <filename unknown>:0    

at ***.ScriptEngine.compile () [0x00036] in
***ScriptEngine.cs:139 }    
System.InvalidOperationException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons, CodeDom failed to spawn a new process to compile source code to temporary assembly. I guess something went wrong while dealing with permission. See below trace:

```
converting method System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor:ExecWaitWithCapture (string,System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection,string&,string&)
Method System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor:ExecWaitWithCapture (string,System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection,string&,string&) emitted at 0x42060b90 to 0x42060bd5 (code length 69) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor:InternalExecWaitWithCapture (string,string,System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection,string&,string&)
Method System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor:InternalExecWaitWithCapture (string,string,System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection,string&,string&) emitted at 0x42060c00 to 0x42061080 (code length 1152) [MyApp.exe]
converting method (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:.ctor ()
Method (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:.ctor () emitted at 0x42061150 to 0x42061189 (code length 57) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.Process:.ctor ()
Method System.Diagnostics.Process:.ctor () emitted at 0x420611a0 to 0x420611b5 (code length 21) [MyApp.exe]
converting method (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:get_StartInfo ()
Method (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:get_StartInfo () emitted at 0x420611c0 to 0x42061222 (code length 98) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.Process:get_StartInfo ()
Method System.Diagnostics.Process:get_StartInfo () emitted at 0x42061240 to 0x420612d0 (code length 144) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:.ctor ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:.ctor () emitted at 0x420612e0 to 0x42061302 (code length 34) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:.cctor ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:.cctor () emitted at 0x42061310 to 0x42061338 (code length 40) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_FileName (string)
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_FileName (string) emitted at 0x42061340 to 0x420613a0 (code length 96) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_CreateNoWindow (bool)
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_CreateNoWindow (bool) emitted at 0x420613a0 to 0x420613bf (code length 31) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_UseShellExecute (bool)
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_UseShellExecute (bool) emitted at 0x420613c0 to 0x420613df (code length 31) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_RedirectStandardOutput (bool)
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_RedirectStandardOutput (bool) emitted at 0x420613e0 to 0x420613ff (code length 31) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_RedirectStandardError (bool)
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_RedirectStandardError (bool) emitted at 0x42061400 to 0x4206141f (code length 31) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_WorkingDirectory (string)
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:set_WorkingDirectory (string) emitted at 0x42061420 to 0x42061480 (code length 96) [MyApp.exe]
converting method (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
Method (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start () emitted at 0x42061480 to 0x420614e2 (code length 98) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
Method System.Diagnostics.Process:Start () emitted at 0x42061500 to 0x42061555 (code length 85) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.Process:Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,System.Diagnostics.Process)
Method System.Diagnostics.Process:Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,System.Diagnostics.Process) emitted at 0x42061560 to 0x420616d0 (code length 368) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_FileName ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_FileName () emitted at 0x42061730 to 0x4206175e (code length 46) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_StandardErrorEncoding ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_StandardErrorEncoding () emitted at 0x42061760 to 0x42061774 (code length 20) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_StandardOutputEncoding ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_StandardOutputEncoding () emitted at 0x42061780 to 0x42061794 (code length 20) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_UseShellExecute ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_UseShellExecute () emitted at 0x420617a0 to 0x420617b4 (code length 20) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.Process:Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,System.Diagnostics.Process)
Method System.Diagnostics.Process:Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,System.Diagnostics.Process) emitted at 0x420617c0 to 0x420630d8 (code length 6424) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_HaveEnvVars ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_HaveEnvVars () emitted at 0x420631c0 to 0x420631e9 (code length 41) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_RedirectStandardInput ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_RedirectStandardInput () emitted at 0x420631f0 to 0x42063204 (code length 20) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_RedirectStandardOutput ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_RedirectStandardOutput () emitted at 0x42063210 to 0x42063224 (code length 20) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.Process:get_IsWindows ()
Method System.Diagnostics.Process:get_IsWindows () emitted at 0x42063230 to 0x4206327a (code length 74) [MyApp.exe]
converting method (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.MonoIO:CreatePipe (intptr&,intptr&)
Method (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.MonoIO:CreatePipe (intptr&,intptr&) emitted at 0x42063280 to 0x4206330d (code length 141) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_RedirectStandardError ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_RedirectStandardError () emitted at 0x42063310 to 0x42063324 (code length 20) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.Process:FillUserInfo (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,System.Diagnostics.Process/ProcInfo&)
Method System.Diagnostics.Process:FillUserInfo (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,System.Diagnostics.Process/ProcInfo&) emitted at 0x42063330 to 0x42063468 (code length 312) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_UserName ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_UserName () emitted at 0x42063490 to 0x420634be (code length 46) [MyApp.exe]
converting method (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.Process:CreateProcess_internal (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,intptr,intptr,intptr,System.Diagnostics.Process/ProcInfo&)
Method (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.Process:CreateProcess_internal (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,intptr,intptr,intptr,System.Diagnostics.Process/ProcInfo&) emitted at 0x420634c0 to 0x42063570 (code   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_ExitCode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:get_ExitCode ()
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.InternalExecWaitWithCapture (System.String cmd, System.String currentDir, System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection tempFiles, System.String& outputName, System.String& errorName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture (System.String cmd, System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection tempFiles, System.String& outputName, System.String& errorName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeCompiler.Compile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames, Boolean keepFiles) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeCompiler.FromSourceBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] sources) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeCompiler.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] sources) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] sources) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at com.example.myapp.ScriptEngine.compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
length 176) [MyApp.exe]
converting method (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_helper_ldstr (intptr,intptr)
Method (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_helper_ldstr (intptr,intptr) emitted at 0x42063570 to 0x420635f9 (code length 137) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_Arguments ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_Arguments () emitted at 0x42063600 to 0x4206362e (code length 46) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_WorkingDirectory ()
Method System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo:get_WorkingDirectory () emitted at 0x42063630 to 0x4206365e (code length 46) [MyApp.exe]
converting method (wrapper managed-to-native) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:W32ErrorMessage (int)
Method (wrapper managed-to-native) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:W32ErrorMessage (int) emitted at 0x42063660 to 0x420636e1 (code length 129) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:.ctor (int,string)
Method System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:.ctor (int,string) emitted at 0x420636f0 to 0x42063727 (code length 55) [MyApp.exe]
converting method (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:get_ExitCode ()
Method (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:get_ExitCode () emitted at 0x42063740 to 0x420637a2 (code length 98) [MyApp.exe]
converting method System.Diagnostics.Process:get_ExitCode ()
Method System.Diagnostics.Process:get_ExitCode () emitted at 0x420637c0 to 0x42063864 (code length 164) [MyApp.exe]
converting method (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.StackTrace:get_trace (System.Exception,int,bool)
Method (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.StackTrace:get_trace (System.Exception,int,bool) emitted at 0x42063890 to 0x42063924 (code length 148) [MyApp.exe]
```

It looked to me that it's time to try something new. Then I changed my code as below:

```
#if LINUX
bool writeOk = true;
string tmpScriptName = String.Format("/tmp/com.myapp.script-{0}.js", Environment.TickCount);
try {
    File.WriteAllText(tmpScriptName, scriptCode);
} catch (Exception) {
    writeOk = false;
} finally {
    if (writeOk) {
        result = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, tmpScriptName);
        try {
            File.Delete(tmpScriptName);
        } catch (Exception) { }
    }
}

#else
result = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, scriptCode);
#endif
```

Fortunately, it works again.

Answer (score 1):

Codedom is a little weird on Linux. It's not implemented the same as it is on Windows, and that's if its implemented at all. If you intend to make a cross-platform application, I would suggest either Mono's [compiler as a service](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/), or [CS-Script's](http://www.csscript.net/) more friendly implementation. Compiler as a service isn't well documented and doesn't work the same as Microsoft's runtime compiler. CS-Script is a wrapper for both Microsoft's and Mono's runtime compilers and it's well documented and straight forward.